Data is not corrected after reordering if there are groupRowsBy?
I created a table with groupRowsBy and can reorder rows, but the result does not change after dragging and dropping the rows. Please help me with this case.
 this.data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    groupOrder: 1,
    group_by: { name: 'Manager', id: 1 },
    name: 'Manager 1',
    title: '1.1 Manager 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: 1.2,
    groupOrder: 1,
    group_by: { name: 'Manager', id: 1 },
    name: 'Manager 2 ',
    title: '1.2 Manager 2',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    groupOrder: 2,
    group_by: { name: 'Support', id: 2 },
    name: 'Support',
    title: '2.1 Support',
  },
];

Row Group Subheader
enter link description here
Reorder
enter link description here
This my code
enter link description here

please share the steps for replication of the issue

please avoid using screenshot why?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

thank. i changed my question

@DarkBee reopen my question please!

I am guessing the problem you are facing is that on drag and drop the datasource (this.data) is not updated. We need to do this programatically using the table row re-order event.

When you drag and drop, instead of listening to the drag event, you can listen for the prime-ng table event onRowReorder.
<div class="card">
  <!-- remove groupRowsBy="group_by.id" will corrcet data afert drop ??? -->
  <p-table
    [value]="data"
    sortMode="single"
    [scrollable]="true"
    rowGroupMode="subheader"
    groupRowsBy="group_by.id"
    (onRowReorder)="onRowReorder($event)"
  >
  ...

This provides you two details dragIndex and dropIndex .We can use these two details and swap the array elements, I have used the move element to another position in array answer below:
Move an array element from one array position to another
onRowReorder(data: any) {
  console.log(data);
  array_move(this.data, data.dragIndex, data.dropIndex);
}

Full Code:
TS:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImportsModule } from './imports';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
  if (new_index >= arr.length) {
    var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
    while (k--) {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return arr; // for testing
}

@Component({
  selector: 'table-subheader-grouping-demo',
  templateUrl: 'table-subheader-grouping-demo.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule, CommonModule],
})
export class TableSubheaderGroupingDemo implements OnInit {
  data: any[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        groupOrder: 1,
        group_by: { name: 'Manager', id: 1 },
        name: 'Manager 1',
        title: '1.1 Manager 1',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        code: 1.2,
        groupOrder: 1,
        group_by: { name: 'Manager', id: 1 },
        name: 'Manager 2 ',
        title: '1.2 Manager 2',
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        groupOrder: 2,
        group_by: { name: 'Support', id: 2 },
        name: 'Support',
        title: '2.1 Support',
      },
    ];
  }

  rowTrackBy(_, item: any) {
    return item.id;
  }

  onRowReorder(data: any) {
    array_move(this.data, data.dragIndex, data.dropIndex);
  }
}

HTML:
<div class="card">
  <!-- remove groupRowsBy="group_by.id" will corrcet data afert drop ??? -->
  <p-table
    [value]="data"
    sortMode="single"
    [scrollable]="true"
    rowGroupMode="subheader"
    groupRowsBy="group_by.id"
    (onRowReorder)="onRowReorder($event)"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>item</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="groupheader" let-item>
      <tr pRowGroupHeader>
        <td colspan="100" class="font-weight-bold">{{ item.group_by.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      <tr pDraggable="item" [pReorderableRow]="rowIndex">
        <td>
          <span class="pi pi-bars" pReorderableRowHandle></span>
        </td>
        <td>{{ item.code }} {{ item.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>

Stackblitz Demo

thank bro. There is an issue that has arisen: moving within one group works correctly, but moving between different groups does not work correctly. Could you please fix this for me? Thank you.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/2s4ltq-vxqbaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-subheader-grouping-demo.ts
